# How do you make a function detect whether a string is binary safe or not

Tags: string, go

How does one detect if a string is binary safe or not in Go?

A function like:

```
IsBinarySafe(str) //returns true if its safe and false if its not.
```

Any comment after this are just things I have thought or attempted to solve this:

---

I assumed that there must exist a library that already does this but had a tough time finding it. If there isn't one, how do you implement this?

I was thinking of some solution but wasn't really convinced they were good solutions.
One of them was to iterate over the bytes, and have a hash map of all the illegal byte sequences.
I also thought of maybe writing a regex with all the illegal strings but wasn't sure if that was a good solution.
I also was not sure if a sequence of bytes from other languages counted as binary safe. Say the typical golang example:

```
世界
```

Would:

```
IsBinarySafe(世界) //true or false?
```

Would it return true or false? I was assuming that all binary safe string should only use 1 byte. So iterating over it in the [following way](http://blog.golang.org/strings):

```
const nihongo = "日本語abc日本語"
    for i, w := 0, 0; i < len(nihongo); i += w {
        runeValue, width := utf8.DecodeRuneInString(nihongo[i:])
        fmt.Printf("%#U starts at byte position %d\n", runeValue, i)
        w = width
    }
```

and returning false whenever the width was great than 1. These are just some ideas I had just in case there wasn't a library for something like this already but I wasn't sure.

Comment: What does 'binary safe' mean?

Comment: UTF-8 strings like `"日本語"` are fine in Go and in most Internet standards these days. (Bonus post from Rob Pike, a designer of Go and of UTF-8, too: http://blog.golang.org/strings) Some characters take more than one byte or even rune, but that's OK. If there's a specific situation where `"日本語"` doesn't work, ask about that: there *should* be a way to make it work, and if not, we can give more guidance once we know the situation.

Comment: @topskip according to wikipedia: `Binary-safe is a computer programming term mainly used in connection with string manipulating functions. A binary-safe function is essentially one that treats its input as a raw stream of data without any specific format. It should thus work with all 256 possible values that a character can take (assuming 8-bit characters).`

Comment: @CharlieParker OK then I'd say that you don't need to do anything special, as Go is binary safe by default. Go doesn't need any special setting to handle all 256 different values of the bytes, and strings are just a concatenation of bytes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Binary safety has nothing to do with how wide a character is, it's mainly to check for non-printable characters more or less, like null bytes and such.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_safe):

> Binary-safe is a computer programming term mainly used in connection
>   with string manipulating functions. A binary-safe function is
>   essentially one that treats its input as a raw stream of data without
>   any specific format. It should thus work with all 256 possible values
>   that a character can take (assuming 8-bit characters).

I'm not sure what your goal is, almost all languages handle utf8/16 just fine now, however for your specific question there's a rather simple solution:

```
// checks if s is ascii and printable, aka doesn't include tab, backspace, etc.
func IsAsciiPrintable(s string) bool {
    for _, r := range s {
        if r > unicode.MaxASCII || !unicode.IsPrint(r) {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("len([]rune(s)) = %d, len([]byte(s)) = %d\n", len([]rune(s)), len([]byte(s)))

    fmt.Println(IsAsciiPrintable(s), IsAsciiPrintable("test"))
}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/xI-PM1WAwo)

From [`unicode.IsPrint`](http://golang.org/pkg/unicode/#IsPrint):

> IsPrint reports whether the rune is defined as printable by Go. Such
>   characters include letters, marks, numbers, punctuation, symbols, and
>   the ASCII space character, from categories L, M, N, P, S and the ASCII
>   space character. This categorization is the same as IsGraphic except
>   that the only spacing character is ASCII space, U+0020.

Comment: Now that I think about it, I think one of my confusions is that even thought I know what "binary safe" is, I have never seen a list of the characters that are not binary safe ("illegal"). I see your code works on some of the inputs I expected, but how am I sure that it works on all binary unsafe strings? Thanks btw!

Comment: Because of `unicode.IsPrint`, also when you're unsure of something, test it. try `IsAsciiPrintable(string([]byte(0, 0, 0))}` for example.

Comment: I guess the point of my question/comment was that is was hard to "test" it because i wasn't sure 100% what was not considered a binary safe char.

Comment: Again binary safety has nothing to do with this, using only printable ascii characters ensures that it's well, ascii and can be "printed".

Comment: I do not mean to be rude and I apologize if it comes out that way. I am just confused why you are saying it has nothing to do with binary safety, my original question's main focus is on binary safety, it has all to do with binary safety, doesn't it? I just want to understand your point and were my misconception occurred. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Binary safety means the function won't break if you pass non-string characters to it, for example trying print "5432\0", where `\0` is a null character, that was a problem maybe 10 years ago, almost all languages and functions can handle that without any problems now (C excluded of course). So all strings are binary safe in go more or less.

Comment: I think I just realized that its pretty hard to guarantee a string is binary safe because according to the definition,it just means that any function that takes it as input should behave as if it was a raw stream of data.However, it seems to me that its pretty hard to guarantee that any function would do that unless its already binary safe.For example, if my function is return "foo" if the first char is "a", then its not binary safe because I took an action based on the encoding of the first string, right? Basically, It seems to me it doesn't really make sense to say any string is binary safe.

Comment: Though, it a string is approximately (with high probability) "binary safe" if it doesn't contain any special characters or non-printables like you said. If it avoid things like `\r\n` and stuff like that.

Comment: Basically, my point is, even if my string contains non-printable characters, if the function already does not behave "binary safe", even if it does not contain special chars or non-printables, it might not behave binary safe for every function there exists. I guess its my point.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57114/discussion-between-oneofone-and-charlie-parker).

Comment: Note that the definition y'all have posted from Wikipedia calls binary safety a trait of string-manipulating *functions* (it means "this function is safe for handling binary data") not of *strings*. The Go standard library handles strings like "日本語" OK. Any bytes can be in a string, as Rob Pike's post noted (http://blog.golang.org/strings). If there's some case where Unicode doesn't work right for you, entirely reasonable to post a question about that. But I think the main takeaway here is that you don't really have to worry much.

Comment: I just realized what my confusion was. I was reading that the redis protocol uses binary safe strings. But what it mean is that, the parser receiving messages from redis, is able to behave as a binary safe string ALWAYS, regardless of the bytes it received, because it appended the length of the string before the data content. So the receiver of the data didn't have to worry about weird characters in the data content because it can always use the length to extract what it needs. Thanks everyone :)